S3 throws 403 when I restrict role to vpce policy using principal
I wanted to restrict my VPC Endpoint policy with by specifying my IAM role in principal
doc which I followed: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/privatelink/vpc-endpoints-access.html
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "aws:PrincipalArn": [
                        "arn:aws:iam::123456789:role/s3-full-access-role
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}

above is the role, After adding this role all the private bucket was working fine i was able to wget objects and copy files from EKS pod etc... But when I try to wget from a public bucket from the EKS pod I got 403 forbidden, Since its public bucket I tried from my local laptop I was able to download object
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 403 Forbidden
2024-07-08 10:42:05 ERROR 403: Forbidden.

From my local:
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK

need help and guidance in debugging this issue
ps: IAM role has s3 cull access, public S3 doesnt have any policy
also when I keep default policy of vpce it starts working, but when I specify principal it wont work :)
